# Add custom class to views row depending on field value

Tags: views, 8, theming

I'm using views to show different fields of an entity. If the uid of the entity is the current user I would like to add a custom class to the entire row (not only to the field).

I wrote the following preprocess function that works fine if I use the entity in views, but I don't know how to change it when I use fields instead:

```
function my_module_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {

  $view = $variables['view'];

  if ($view->id() == 'my_view' && $view->current_display == 'page_1') {

    $rows = $variables['rows'];
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {

      $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

      $owner = $row['content']['uid']['#object']->get('uid')->getString();

      $class = ($uid == $owner) ? 'own' : 'other';

      $custom_row_class = 'views-row-' . $class;
      $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']->addClass($custom_row_class);
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you please try the following code snippet. I swapped the line to retrieve the author's user ID.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function MYMODULE_preprocess_views_view_unformatted(&$variables) {

  $view = $variables['view'];
  if ($view->id() == 'MY_VIEW' && $view->current_display == 'MY_DISPLAY') {

    $uid = \Drupal::currentUser()->id();

    $rows = $variables['rows'];
    foreach ($rows as $id => $row) {

      // Get user ID.
      $owner = $row['content']['#row']->_entity->get('uid')->target_id;

      $class = ($uid == $owner) ? 'own' : 'other';
      $custom_row_class = 'views-row-' . $class;

      $variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']->addClass($custom_row_class);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, works fine. How can I make it more generic to support both use cases, i.e. how do I evaluate whether the view shows an entity or fields?
Unfortunatelly I'm not able to inspect the variables as I always get an error when I try to use kint. Is there a better way?

Comment: Thanks @raj, Thats work like a charm for me :), thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Raj Had to change '$view->id()' to '$view->storage->id()' in drupal 8.5 in order for it to work. Thanks!

Comment: In 8.5, last line need to changed to
`$variables['rows'][$id]['attributes']['class'][] =$css_class;`